# Import Coordinate System as Marker in MSC Adams

Tags: solidworks, simulation

A very simple question, yet I couldn't find an answer: I created a simple part (e.g. in SolidWorks) with one solid body and two Coordinate Systems. I would like to place my Joints, Revolutes, etc. in Adams on the already existing Coordinate Systems from SolidWorks. Therefore, it would be necessary to import the two Coordinate Systems as Adams Markers. How can I do this?

[image: Import Coordinate System from e.g. SolidWorks as Marker in MSC Adams]

Comment: Write locations to text file and recreate in adams.

Comment: Yes, that was my thought too, but how do I export a Coordinate System from SolidWorks to a .txt file?

Comment: Place a coordinate system in the file and use the scripting API to get the matrix of given coordinate system and write the matrix down. Covert matrix to euler angle write into a adams script file. Its pretty sytraightforward. I would share my master thesis code if i were entrirely certain of the copyright owner of the code and if i would think anybody would be able to run the suftware.  Its made for creo but the basis is the same. (it also contains layers of layers of crap that the other users and academics  were requuestion even if in the end only the part i did foer myself was used)

Comment: I will outline thi in a answer